# Connect to ASPState database from APP server instead of WEB server

Tags: sql, asp.net, wcf, architecture, aspstate

We deploy our application in three tier model. UI on web server, Services on App server and database is on different server. From UI (web server) we dont allow database connections directly and it should go through our own services deployed on APP server. So far we are using Inproc as session state but now we would like to maintain the session state in SQL server. As per my knowledge we have to edit our UI config to add the SQL server connection string like below to make calls to the ASPState DB. Since as per our company policy we cannot access the DB from web server, the below connection string will not work.

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

With the aboveinformation, is there any way to achieve SQLServer as session state with our setup? Please advice.

Comment: try to refer to the following link.https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/484ad3/session-state-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Thank You. Its a nice article but i didn't get answer to my question.